# Case Comment create Permission from Community Portal?

Tags: customer-community, napili, community-builder

I need a help regarding Case comments on Community Portal. Currently, I have created Sharing set to Display logged-in Contact Cases in Portal and they have case create permission too. I have enabled Case Comment related list to that Case. But now I am able to see public Case comments in Community Portal but I cannot create case comments from community Portal. So, Where I can enable that permission.

Need a new button on Case Comment related list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Manoj, You need to include Case Comments publisher component on the case detail page. Please follow this [article](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.community_templates.meta/community_templates/rss_case_publisher.htm)

> **Case Comments Publisher**  
>  
> Use the Case Comments Publisher component to
>   let customers and agents collaborate using comments on cases. Your
>   customers can open cases, post comments, upload attachments, and check
>   the status of their cases from any of their devices.